# Call viewdidload from appDelegate

Tags: ios, ios7, appdelegate, viewdidload

I want to call the viewDidLoad in my view controller from my appDelegate. How do I do so?

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    TCAViewController *uiTCA = [[TCAViewController alloc] init];

    if(uiTCA.failed == 1){

        //Here I want to call viewDidLoad

// I thought something like this would work but I get an error
// [self uiTCA.viewDidLoad];


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't call `viewDidLoad`, the system calls it when all the outlets have been set on the view controller.

Create a method `- (void)doSomething;` in your `TCAViewController` class and call that in your AppDelegate.

```
[uiTVA doSomething];
```